# Win7 --> Win8 = Bitlocker won't ask for password

Tags: windows-8, disk-encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I have a Dell E6520 laptop with a TPM. It had Windows 7 Enterprise x64. The **C** (boot) partition  is encrypted with Bitlocker. Bitlocker would prompt me for a password after POST, and after I entered the password, the OS booted.

I installed Windows 8 x64 Enterprise by inserting the DVD while Windows 7 was running, and I used the option that shoved all my current stuff over into a **c:\windows.old** directory. Before the installation started, I suspended Bitlocker.

After the Windows 8 installation was done, I resumed Bitlocker. Now I do not get a  Bitlocker password prompt after POST. The computer does POST, pauses a couple of seconds, then reboots, cycling endlessly. I can only get around this by inserting a USB stick with my Bitlocker recovery key.

I then unencrypted and re-encrypted the C drive. I cleared the TPM before I re-encrypted.

During Bitlocker setup, I was never prompted to enter a password or to select an option other than to back up my encryption key. I am still stuck in the state where if I don't have a USB drive handy with the recovery key, I cannot boot the computer as it simply reboots right after POST.

I set an owner password set on the TPM after the Bitlocker encryption was done.

How do I restore the functionality I had with Windows 7, where instead of needing a physical USB key, I could just enter a Bootlocker password to boot the OS?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the TPM itself.  I don't know enough about the particular TPM to give a more direct answer, but I'd start by looking at the documentation for the particular TPM you have in relation to BitLocker.

Comment: Why would the TPM have worked properly with Win7 but not Win8?

Comment: it's possible that it was somehow tied to the bootloader of the OS.  I'm not sure exactly how, but I know I've had problems with TPMs getting confused when I changed the OS.  Something about it seems to partially reinitialize them or something.  I just know I've seen problems in the past with TPMs I've used (mostly in ThinkPads).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. I did clear the TPM before I re-encrypted the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was related to the group policy settings for the domain I was on. The group policy settings that caused Windows 7 to force a password every time you turned on the laptop did not for for Windows 8.